# Offline HTML5 .html pages - need to include file into another file

Tags: javascript, html, include

We have an offline set of HTML pages we're working with using HTML5 document type. We want to include our sub-navigation via a `<script src="____">` but for some reason it's not including. Is there some other method of including the file without needing server-side assistance somewhere?

Because of how we're delivering these files to the client we must work offline, but it would seriously suck to have to update 100 files due to a simple sub-nav change that could be globally included via Javascript somehow.

Comment: As a further example, let's imagine we're totally offline with our HTML (no server) as if we're putting these onto a CD-Rom or DVD. I'm guessing there may be some clever trick with Ajax that I'm not thinking of just yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could put an empty div

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

And then "load" that with jQuery

```
$("#navigation").load("path/to/nav/file.html");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I found this page which works in Firefox (perfectly) but IE requires an ActiveX prompt (due to external content) where Chrome doesn't work at all.  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxincludes.shtml

Comment: @Will: Sure, look at the jQuery source and figure out how the `load()` function works. You can probably slice everything you need out of there. Make sure to get the unminified source.

Comment: Actually, what you posted works everywhere except for Google Chrome browser. Firefox and IE are good to go. Any ideas why Chrome sucks in this one instance?

Comment: @Will Ashworth: Chrome seems to have some issues when working with files on localhost (on Ubuntu this is applicable to both `/var/www/index.html` *and* `localhost/index.html`). It *might* behave differently if the file's accessed on the internet.

Comment: @Will: What @David said. I would recommend finding an absolute path for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

External HTML code can be included via .js file. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="include_html.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            paragraph();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Contents of include_html.js

```
function paragraph()
{
        document.write("<p> This is an HTML paragraph </p>");
}
```